# Sequence Contains No Elements Error In C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq, c#-4.0

I am making an API call and an error of `sequence contains no elements` in my syntax below I am using `.First()` but when using `.FirstOrDefault()` I get the same error.  How should this syntax be changed so that this error is not presented?

```
public class Root 
{ 
    public List<AI> AI { get; set; } 
} 
public class AI 
{ 
    public List<Dictionary<string, string>> AddressInfo { get; set; } 
} 

public class Main[] 
{ 
    var response = syncClient.DownloadString(url); 
    var returnData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root[]>(response); 
    foreach (Root ro in returnData) 
    {
        foreach (AI info in ro.AI) 
        { 
            string address = info.AddressInfo.First()["Address1"]); 
            string address2 =  info.AddressInfo.First()["Address2"]); 
            string city = info.AddressInfo.First()["City"]);
            string state =  info.AddressInfo.First()["State"]);
            string zip =  info.AddressInfo.First()["Zip"]);
            Conesole.ReadLine();
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking for a null object:

```
foreach (AI info in ro.AI) 
{ 
    var addressInfo = info.AddressInfo.FirstOrDefault();

    if(addressInfo != null)
    {
        string address = addressInfo["Address1"]; 
        string address2 = addressInfo["Address2"]; 
        string city = addressInfo["City"];
        string state = addressInfo["State"];
        string zip = addressInfo["Zip"];

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to remove the closing paren but other than that it worked great!  Thank you for othat